# Detect when select or text boxes are populated via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

This may sound like a strange question, but hopefully there is an answer out there.

I have a number of select and text boxes in my HTML page.  These boxes get populated at some point after the page is loaded and I have no control when they are; I just know that eventually after the page loads the boxes will be filled.

Is there any way to create a listener that can detect when these get populated?

I have been using setInterval/clearInterval, but I was hoping jQuery had a way of "listening" for when these get populated.

Thoughts?

Comment: do they get value from the user or by code?

Comment: does the event change/keyup work for you? Also, you dont have control of the script that populates the fields?

Comment: To clarify, (and I know this sounds weird), but I nor the user have any control when the inputs are populated.  Basically once the page loads the fields get populated somehow.  All I have is an empty select and text box that will eventually get filled by some timing on the server end.  I don't have visibility what causes that to happen, I just need to know WHEN it happens so I can use the data sent to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If their values are being set by the user the you can listen to the change event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input, select').change(function() {
        var $changedElement = $(this);

        if($changedElement.val() != '') {
            // code to keep track of which elements are checked..
        }
    });
});
```

If elements are being added to the page from script after the page load you'll need to use `live` rather than `change`

```
$('input, select').live('change' function() {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to, well, *trigger* the `change`  event, and [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to listen out for the `change` event:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        // basically put .trigger('change') after whatever function populates the inputs
        $('form input').populateInputFunction().trigger('change');

    $('input').change(
        function(){
            // do whatever you want to do when the inputs are changed
        });

    });
```

Without seeing your code it's hard to say exactly how to use them in your page, but hopefully the above example should provide some insight.

From your question it's also ambiguous as to where the change comes from. If it comes from your own jQuery actions then the above should work, if it's coming from the user's actions then you simply have to listen out for the `change()` event on the `input`s (the latter section `$('input').change()`).

Comment: David ~ since there really isn't a function that populates the input (see my comment to my original post), is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Mark: listening for the `change()` event should still work, though I'm fascinated by the somewhat-magical events leading to the population of your inputs.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well enough how to do this.  My HTML page basically gets data from a platform.  In order for that data to come into my page I send a parameter to the platform and it returns the results to either a select or text box.  The time for the data to return is unknown, but once the data does come back I need to do things with it; thus the need to know when the data comes back. In essence, I know when I send the parameter, but not sure how or when the data comes back.  I'm not familiar with AJAX in jQuery, but does this sound like something viable AJAX could handle?